# Access database runtime error 13 type mismatch

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

First time posting... I'm sure this is probably something simple so I apologize in advance. This is actually my first time ever working with the VBA and I've come to a problem. I've searched and tried multiple things but still the same problem despite anything I try.

I've moved database to another machine and now I get runtime error 13. Debugger says it's at line 28:

```
Me!odf = CVDate("01.01.1800")
```

It's when you click on button which opens new window for searching the database with specific criteria set by user.

Here is the code:

```
    VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Form_Pregledt"
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Option Compare Database
Private Sub Angioloski_Click()
  Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.RowSource = "SELECT [Qpregledt].[Idpregleda], [Qpregledt].[Datum], [Qpregledt].[Prezime i ime], [Qpregledt].[Godina rodjenja], [Qpregledt].[Adresa], [Qpregledt].[Telefon], [Qpregledt].[Faks], [Qpregledt].[e-mail] FROM [Qpregledt] WHERE [VRSTA PREGLEDA]=FORMS!PREGLEDT!VRSTA AND [ANGIOLOSKI]=FORMS!PREGLEDT!ANGIOLOSKI  and datum>=forms!pregledt!odf  and datum<=forms!pregledt!dof "
  Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.Requery
  Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!ukupno.Caption = "Ukupno: " & Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.ListCount
  Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub do_AfterUpdate()
If IsNull(Me!od) = True Then
Me!odf = CVDate("01.01.1800")
Else
Me!odf = Me!od
End If
If IsNull(Me!do) = True Then
Me!dof = CVDate("01.01.2800")
Else
Me!dof = Me!do
End If
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.Requery
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!ukupno.Caption = "Ukupno: " & Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.ListCount
Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!ukupno.Caption = "Ukupno: " & Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.ListCount
Me!odf = CVDate("01.01.1800")
Me!dof = CVDate("01.01.2800")
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.Requery
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!ukupno.Caption = "Ukupno: " & Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.ListCount
Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub od_AfterUpdate()
If IsNull(Me!od) = True Then
Me!odf = CVDate("01.01.1800")
Else
Me!odf = Me!od
End If
If IsNull(Me!do) = True Then
Me!dof = CVDate("01.01.2800")
Else
Me!dof = Me!do
End If
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.Requery
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!ukupno.Caption = "Ukupno: " & Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.ListCount
Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub vrsta_Click()
If Me!vrsta = 1 Then
 Me!Angioloski.Enabled = True
 Else
 Me!Angioloski.Enabled = False
 Me!Angioloski = Null
End If
If IsNull(Me!vrsta) = False Then
 If IsNull(Me!Angioloski) = True Then
  Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.RowSource = "SELECT [Qpregledt].[Idpregleda], [Qpregledt].[Datum], [Qpregledt].[Prezime i ime], [Qpregledt].[Godina rodjenja], [Qpregledt].[Adresa], [Qpregledt].[Telefon], [Qpregledt].[Faks], [Qpregledt].[e-mail] FROM [Qpregledt] WHERE [VRSTA PREGLEDA]=FORMS!PREGLEDT!VRSTA and datum>=forms!pregledt!odf  and datum<=forms!pregledt!dof "
 Else
  Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.RowSource = "SELECT [Qpregledt].[Idpregleda], [Qpregledt].[Datum], [Qpregledt].[Prezime i ime], [Qpregledt].[Godina rodjenja], [Qpregledt].[Adresa], [Qpregledt].[Telefon], [Qpregledt].[Faks], [Qpregledt].[e-mail] FROM [Qpregledt] WHERE [VRSTA PREGLEDA]=FORMS!PREGLEDT!VRSTA AND [ANGIOLOSKI]=FORMS!PREGLEDT!ANGIOLOSKI  and datum>=forms!pregledt!odf  and datum<=forms!pregledt!dof"
 End If
End If
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.Requery
Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!ukupno.Caption = "Ukupno: " & Forms!PREGLEDT!Pregledf.Form!Idpregleda.ListCount
Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub izlaz_Click()
'On Error GoTo Err_izlaz_Click
On Error Resume Next

    DoCmd.Close

Exit_izlaz_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_izlaz_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_izlaz_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: try separating your dates with `/` instead of `.` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Tim says in the comments, your date separator is wrong. However, personally I'd avoid the ambiguities of strings in the first place (what date is 01/03/02?) and use the `DateSerial` function:

```
Me!odf = DateSerial(1800, 1, 1)
```